# More than two matrices multiplied in tensor notation

Tags: matrices, tensors, index-notation

I know that the $(i,k)$ element of a matrix product is expressed in tensor notation as:

$$M^i_{\:k} = A^i_{\:j}B^j_{\:k}$$

But I'm a little confused as to what happens in the notation when the product involves more than two matrices.
$$Q^i_{\:k} = A^i_{\:j}B^?_{\:?} C^?_{\:?}$$

Also, say the elements of $A$ and $B$ are functions of corresponding elements of a vector $x$.

$$A^i_{\:j} = f(x_i, x_j)$$

$$B^i_{\:j} = g(x_i, x_j)$$

Same function $f()$ for all entries in $A$, and likewise same function $g()$ for all entries in $B$, just with different variables $x_i, x_j$ corresponding to the matrix indices.

How to represent differentiation of $M^i_{\:k}$ and $Q^i_{\:k}$ w.r.t. $x_i$

$$\frac{\partial M^i_{\:k}}{\partial x_i}=?$$
$$\frac{\partial Q^i_{\:k}}{\partial x_i}=?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is 
$$Q^i{}_k=A^i{}_jB^j{}_rC^r{}_k.$$

For the differentiation one uses the Leibniz's Rule:
$$\frac{\partial M^i{}_k}{\partial x^u}=
\frac{\partial A^i{}_j}{\partial x^u}B^j{}_k
+A^i{}_j\frac{\partial B^j{}_k}{\partial x^u},$$
and then take $u=i$ for the contraction.

Comment: So just to be clear: $\frac{\partial A^i_{\:j}}{\partial x^i}B^j_{\:k}=\frac{\partial A^i_{\:1}}{\partial x^i}B^1_{\:k}+\frac{\partial A^i_{\:2}}{\partial x^i}B^2_{\:k}+...+\frac{\partial A^i_{\:n}}{\partial x^i}B^n_{\:k}$?

Comment: yes, sure, ok .